# Breadth first traversal of arbitrary graph with minimal memory

Tags: graph, hashset, breadth-first-search

I have an enormous directed graph I need to traverse in search for the shortest path to a specific node from a given starting point. The graph in question does not exist explicitly; the child nodes are determined algorithmically from the parent nodes.
(To give an illustration: imagine a graph of chess positions. Each node is a chess position and its children are all the legal moves from that position.)
So I have a queue for open nodes, and every time I process the next node in the queue I enqueue all of its children. But since the graph can have cycles I also need to maintain a hashset of all visited nodes so I can check if I have visited one before.
This works okay, but since this graph is so large, I run into memory problems. All of the nodes in the queue are also stored in the hashset, which tends to be around 50% of the total number or visited nodes in practice in my case.
Is there some magical way to get rid of this redundancy while keeping the speed of the hashset? (Obviously, I could get rid of the redundancy by NOT hashing and just doing a linear search, but that is out of the question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by writing a class that stores the keys in a list and stores the indices of the keys in a hashtable. The next node "in the queue" is always the the next node in the list until you find what you're looking for or you've traversed the entire graph.

```
class IndexMap<T>
{
    private List<T> values;
    private LinkedList<int>[] buckets;
    public int Count { get; private set; } = 0;

    public IndexMap(int capacity)
    {
        values = new List<T>(capacity);
        buckets = new LinkedList<int>[NextPowerOfTwo(capacity)];
        for (int i = 0; i < buckets.Length; ++i)
            buckets[i] = new LinkedList<int>();
    }

    public void Add(T item) //assumes item is not yet in map
    {
        if (Count == buckets.Length)
            ReHash();
        int bucketIndex = item.GetHashCode() & (buckets.Length - 1);
        buckets[bucketIndex].AddFirst(Count++);
        values.Add(item);
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        int bucketIndex = item.GetHashCode() & (buckets.Length - 1);
        foreach(int i in buckets[bucketIndex])
        {
            if (values[i].Equals(item))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => values[index];
    }

    private void ReHash()
    {
        LinkedList<int>[] newBuckets = new LinkedList<int>[2 * buckets.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < newBuckets.Length; ++i)
            newBuckets[i] = new LinkedList<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < buckets.Length; ++i)
        {
            foreach (int index in buckets[i])
            {
                int bucketIndex = values[index].GetHashCode() & (newBuckets.Length - 1);
                newBuckets[bucketIndex].AddFirst(index);
            }
            buckets[i] = null;
        }
        buckets = newBuckets;
    }

    private int NextPowerOfTwo(int n)
    {
        if ((n & n-1) == 0)
            return n;
        int output = 0;
        while (n > output)
        {
            output <<= 1;
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

The old method of maintaining both an array of the open nodes and a hashtable of the visited nodes needed n*(1+a)*size(T) space, where a is the ratio of *nodes_in_the_queue* over *total_nodes_found* and size(T) is the size of a node.
This method needs n*(size(T) + size(int)). If your nodes are significantly larger than an int, this can save a lot.